# If there was an EMP from the sun would all of Stack Overflow's data be wiped out?

Tags: discussion, security

May be a silly question, but it is not a field of research I know much about.

Someone I know seems to have a bit of a paranoia about an "Electro Magnetic Pulse from the sun wiping out all data storage".

I don't have enough knowledge in this field to know if it is something to worry about or not, but I was wondering if Stack Overflow's databases are 'protected' against this (possibly) very real threat, or whether it is not something to be concerned about.

Is meta even the right place to be asking this!?

Comment: We don't fear EMPs. Jon Skeet memorizes a complete dump of the database every week.

Comment: Stack Overflow does backups - and I'm pretty sure they're doing them right. Why don't you download a copy of the data dump though, just in case ?

Comment: You will have bigger problems than Stack Overflow's data is wiped out after experiencing a big EMP.

Comment: @JonasCz I might just download the whole internet while I am at it.

Comment: @timhc22 _"I might just download the whole internet while I am at it."_ And save that to some EMP safe medium :-P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, I will carve it in binary into stone

Comment: @tim, it's a good idea, but you won't have enough stone.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi on mars

Comment: See also: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/12118/can-a-solar-flare-destroy-every-electronic-item-on-earth

Comment: @closevoters: This question *is* about Stack Overflow

Comment: @user, yeah, sure. I still voted to close as *unable to reproduce*.

Comment: Related: https://xkcd.com/1508/

Answer (score 23):

Yeah, probably.

Comment: But that would most likely be the least of our worries.

Comment: as long as the radius is less than 1778 miles

Comment: How did you post an answer shorter than the minimum 30 characters ??

Comment: @JonasCz edit his answer. you'll see ;)

Comment: @JonasCz Check the `<!-------------------------------->`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what are you talking about?

Comment: See, if you [totally switched everything to Linux](https://np.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/468p2m/stack_overflow_the_architecture_2016_edition/d03semx), you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: I remember in '97 - the company I worked for had a security audit for some data we needed to acquire and host responsibly. They got shown the safe with the DLT's we had (that was what you did at the time - no cloud stuff)... and other tapes went "off-site" (IIRC we payed a bomb sometimes to get them redelivered to the premises). I remember my manager at the time saying he was asked "So - what'd you do in the event of a nuclear bomb going off in the vicinity"? I think his not unreasonable was "I doubt I'd be f*ing worried about the data any more" :p

Comment: @NickCraver Interesting, it's gone now :-P ...

Comment: I think it's time to start using a [Kryptonian backup storage solution](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2013/jul/17/5d-superman-memory-crystal-heralds-unlimited-lifetime-data-storage).

Answer (score 16):

We have:

- The data in our NY Datacenter (stored on SSD, backups on HDD and LTO tape)
- The data in our CO Datacenter (stored on SSD, backups on HDD)
- Offsite backups in Glacier's West 2 region (stored on ¯\_(ツ)_/¯, presumably LTO tape)

So any wide geographic disaster would need to hit all of these, and an EMP would need to be one that wiped all of the above storage types. The world would have bigger problems.

Comment: Well that settles that then. Phew ;)

Comment: What makes you sure that data backups survive an EMP?

Comment: What world? I'm confused.

Comment: Well, at least it would be the end of all teh sockpuppets.

Comment: I think you underestimate the fallout from Stack Overflow's data being wiped. In this day and age, I doubt the millennials could band together to recreate the world's technology post-EMP _without_ Stack Overflow!